# Check for an img tag in jquery?

Tags: jquery

My div has an image tag inside of it:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <img src="/my_image.jpg">
</div>
```

What would be the JQuery to check if an img existed inside myDiv? So for example, sometimes the page would look like:

```
<div id="myDiv">

</div>
```

The above should return false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$('#myDiv img').length` would be fastest. Since jQuery objects always evaluate to `true` even if there's nothing inside them, you have to get the `.length` and see if it's non-zero.

If the image must be a direct child of `myDiv`, use the direct child selector instead: `$('#myDiv > img').length`

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$("#myDiv").find("img").length;
```

this way is actually faster than `$("#myDiv img")`

http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-speed2

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$("#myDiv").find("img").length
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

```
if($("#myDiv").find('img').lenght > 0)
   console.log('exists');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
$("#myDiv").children("img").length
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (myElems.is(":has(img)")) { 
}
```